# Testing with PICT, but incomplete testcases

Tags: automated-testing, pairwise-testing

I've also already asked this question in Stackoverflow, but I think I would get a better answer here.

I'm testing a triangle problem in PICT. I'm testing if a triangle is an equilateral triangle, an isosceles triangle, or a scalene triangle. The problem is that I never get the equilateral triangle as a result.

```
Side1:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Side2:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Side3:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Type:         equilateral, isosceles, scalene

IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) OR ([Side2] = [Side3]) OR ([Side3] = [Side1])) THEN [Type] = "isosceles"  ELSE [Type] = "scalene";
IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) AND ([Side2] = [Side3]) AND ([Side3] = [Side1])) THEN [Type] = "equilateral";
```

But the random thing here is that when I change the last line into

```
IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) AND ([Side2] = [Side3]) AND ([Side3] = [Side1])) THEN [Type] = "isosceles";
```

I randomly get values that would result in an equilateral triangle. How can I make sure I also have these values in my correct code?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that an equilateral triangle is *also* an isosceles triangle.

Because you have the least restrictive check first, that check will identify all your equilateral triangles as isosceles triangles.

This is a pretty good example of why it's not a good idea to combine multiple checks into a single code routine: you aren't necessarily checking what you think you're checking.

I'd start by checking for equilateral first and see if that gives you the results you're expecting.

Comment: This is not the problem, if I check the code without the last line I wouldn't get values to make an equilateral triangle. If I would check the equilateral first, also no values that would gave the results of equilateral. I even did the check the isosceles with an XOR, still no results of a equilateral. The only way to get values that are equilateral, is for me to change the last line like I did in my example.

Comment: @Kyra - this sounds like the logic engine has a few quirks to it. One thing you might try is removing the last condition from the equilateral check, since `IF A = B AND B = C THEN A = C` (making your third condition redundant - possibly this is confusing the logic engine?)

Comment: Also tried that one, confusing thing is that if I would use this code in any other Pairwise testing tool, and alter it to the syntax, it would work. I can't debug PICT, so I don't know exactly how it works, and why I get the results that I get. So kind of hoping that someone here does knows how it works. Like I said, works with other tools, so not really a big problem. But it's bugging me.